# I want to upload multiple image name in a same row using PHP MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

Here is my code

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES["user_files"]["name"]); $i++) 
{
    // get the image mime type
    $image_mime = strtolower(image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype($_FILES["user_files"]["tmp_name"][$i])));

    if (in_array($image_mime, $valid_image_check)) 
    {
        $folderName = "uploads/";
        $ext = explode("/", strtolower($image_mime));
        $ext = strtolower(end($ext));
        $filename = rand(10000, 990000) . '_' . time() . '.' . $ext;

        // if user upload a file abc,jpg, it will convert it to 291905_1399918178.jpg based on random number and time.
        $filepath = $folderName . $filename;
        if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["user_files"]["tmp_name"][$i], $filepath)) 
        {
              echo "fail uplaod";
        } else {
            $smsg .= "<strong>" . $_FILES["user_files"]["name"][$i] . "</strong> uploaded successfully. <br>";

            $magicianObj = new imageLib($filepath);
            $magicianObj->resizeImage(100, 100);
            $magicianObj->saveImage($folderName . 'thumb/' . $filename, 100);
        }

    } else {
        echo "not image";

    }
}
```

and MySQL query is

```
$sql =  "INSERT INTO properties 
           (agent_id, property_name, category, location, 
            property_type, search_radius, price, bed_rooms, 
            bath_rooms, commercial_type, area, address, 
            description, image_name, date_added)
         VALUES 
           ('$agent_id', '$property_name', '$listing_for', '$city', 
            '$property_type', '$area', '$price', '$beds', 
            '$baths', '$commercial_type', '$area_sf', '$address', 
            '$description', '".$filename."',  now() )" ;
```

so here I need to Insert my all `$filename` values in a single row.

But when I run this script only the last `$filename` is inserted into DB.

How can I  insert my all values of `$filename` from for loop in DB in a single row.

Comment: You should create a new Table lets call it `property_images` and store one row in there for each image you receieve with the `property_id` as the linking field.

Comment: As @RiggsFolly says, if you’re storing multiple images against a record, then you should create another table to hold those images.

Comment: Ok thank you. how to write that code. Could you please answer me?

Comment: Not quite sure why I would want to do all your work for you. Grab a  book and have a go yourself. Come back with specific finite issues and ask another question if you get any specific problems

Comment: @RiggsFolly I dont ask you man.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use a persistent array for this.

```
$fileNames = array();

for ($i = 0; $i < count($_FILES["user_files"]["name"]); $i++)
{
// get the image mime type
$image_mime = strtolower(image_type_to_mime_type(exif_imagetype($_FILES["user_files"]["tmp_name"][$i])));

if (in_array($image_mime, $valid_image_check))
{
    $folderName = "uploads/";
    $ext = explode("/", strtolower($image_mime));
    $ext = strtolower(end($ext));
    $filename = rand(10000, 990000) . '_' . time() . '.' . $ext;

    // if user upload a file abc,jpg, it will convert it to 291905_1399918178.jpg based on random number and time.
    $filepath = $folderName . $filename;
    if (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES["user_files"]["tmp_name"][$i], $filepath))
    {
        echo "fail uplaod";
    } else {
        $smsg .= "<strong>" . $_FILES["user_files"]["name"][$i] . "</strong> uploaded successfully. <br>";

        $magicianObj = new imageLib($filepath);
        $magicianObj->resizeImage(100, 100);
        $magicianObj->saveImage($folderName . 'thumb/' . $filename, 100);
        $fileNames[] = $filepath;
    }

} else {
    echo "not image";
}
}
```

And then in your SQL:

```
$images = rtrim(implode(',', $fileNames), ',');
$sql =  "INSERT INTO properties 
       (agent_id, property_name, category, location, 
        property_type, search_radius, price, bed_rooms, 
        bath_rooms, commercial_type, area, address, 
        description, image_name, date_added)
     VALUES 
       ('$agent_id', '$property_name', '$listing_for', '$city', 
        '$property_type', '$area', '$price', '$beds', 
        '$baths', '$commercial_type', '$area_sf', '$address', 
        '$description', '$images',  now() )" ;
```

This will insert a comma separated list of filenames into the DB.

You may want to have a look at prepared statements from the looks of your query.

You should probably use another table for something like this, which attaches to the property ID.

```
image_id | image_url | property_id
SELECT `image_url` FROM `property_images` WHERE `property_id` = :property_id
```

Something along those lines, as has been commented this is a bad way of doing things.

Comment: Its a solution, but a very poor one.

Comment: I've offered a quick solution the way he wants it done. Could you explain how you would do it better?

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am using your code. But all values are inserted That column image_name is empty. So what can I do now?

Comment: Well yes, but as the solution would be rip it up and start again after doing some reading about database design, **its unlikely that he would even bother reading it**.

Comment: PS. You also now need to worry about coding something that will allow an agent to add to the images for this property, or remove one. Now you have to deal with a comma seperated list of filenames every time you need to make any changes. **Messy, Code intensive, and prone to errors** ReDesign the database

Comment: If he were to look at the second solution of making another table that relates the property_id, then it would solve that problem.

Comment: Yes I see you picked up on my comment from above.

Comment: @RiggsFolly As you told study things and do. I obey your request. I created another table with the reference of `property_id`. Finally I got the output. Thank you.